# Write file on php

Tags: php, ip, fwrite

I want to keep ips from visitors and place them on a file.
I tried fwrite() function but I think it is rewrite on the previus ip on file.

Example.

ip.txt is empty.

when I run the write.php Script, on ip.txt I have x.x.x.x  ip  (my ip)

If My friend runs the write.php Script, on ip.txt I have a.a.a.a  ip (friend's ip only)

where is my ip? 
I want to have on ip.txt file the following:

```
x.x.x.x   ip1  
a.a.a.a   ip2
```

Code on  write.php is the following.

```
<?php
$file = fopen("ip.txt","w");
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
echo fwrite($file,$ip);
fclose($file);
?>
```

Comment: You should use a database.

Comment: I want to write them on a file for more security! Is a misunderstanding that a file is more secure than a msql database?  @jeroen

Comment: There are plenty free open source analytic tools that work with PHP that will do a much better job.

Comment: @John assuming you ran that script in the webroot. All I would have to do is download ip.txt so how is that secure?

Comment: I need it to show on my index page that this guy has visit that page of my site now, or 1 min ago, I couldnt find any script for that purpose. @MathewFoscarini

Comment: John, there is in no way a security risk in entering someones IP into a database. IPs cannot be forged and therefore will do no harm to SQL queries.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini , You have right with downloading, I have only think the permissions about viewing online!  ok, I'll create a db. Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$file = fopen("ip.txt","a");
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
echo fwrite($file,$ip);
fclose($file);
?>
```

Look at the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)

Check what the 2nd parameter means.

Youve chosen `w` mode which is an overrwrite mode. Try `a` mode instead (append)

Answer (score 6):

Change "w" to "a"

W means write (over), a means append.

Answer (score 1):

The 'advantage' of the database version is that no one can view
the data.  If neccesary, you can avoid access to the file by using a .htaccess file:

For apache 2.2

```
# Protect log.txt
<Files ./inscription/log.txt>
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

For apache 2.4

```
# Protect log.txt
<Files ./inscription/log.txt>
Require all denied
</Files>
```